# Javascript PHP - Unexpected delay while processing an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i've been working on a log in form since yesterday and here is how i currently manage the website :

First i'm having a loader.php that is charged of checking the user privileges and showing up elements on the "main.php" page accordingly.

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $status=false;
 if( isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status']==true){
     $status=true;  
 }
 include 'main.php';
 ?>
```

Then there is the "main.php" that i have organised as such :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html>
 <?php if($status): ?>

 <body>
  //DC NC  

   // Main content for logged in users
</body>
<?php else: ?>
<body style="background:url("img/404.png")"></body>
<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

The index is constitued with a log in form that consists in this :

```
<form id="logForm" action="loader.php" method="POST">
            <div class="pom-agile">
                <input placeholder="Login (lname.fname)" name="user" class="user" type="text" required>
                <span class="icon1"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="pom-agile">
                <input  placeholder="password" name="pass" class="pass" type="password" required>
                <span class="icon2"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-w3l">
                <h6><a href="#">Password Forgotten ?</a></h6>
                <div class="right-w3l">
                    <input id="enter" type="submit" value="Enter"><br><br>
                    <input type="button" value="Subscribe" onclick="document.getElementById('reg').style.display='block'">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now this login form is handled with javascript such as so :

```
//My LogForm Handler
$('#logForm').submit(function(){
    $user=document.forms["logForm"]["user"].value;
    var $pass=document.forms["logForm"]["pass"].value;
    for(var i=0;i<$users.length;i++){
        if($users[i]['user'].trim() == $user.trim() && $users[i]['password'] == $pass.trim()){
            if($users[i]['status']==1){
                => AJAX("startSession");
                => alert(); // Debugs the situation but unpractical
                => return true;
            }
            else{
                alert("Your registration is being processed");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Wrong logs");
    return false;
});
```

I use the Ajax function for other calls as well but here is her implementation :

```
function AJAX($call){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
            if($call=="getUsers"){
                $users=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //alert($users.toSource());
            }
        }
    };
    if($call=="getUsers"){
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/www/Chellah/beta/read.php?option=users",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    if($call=="startSession"){
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/www/Chellah/beta/read.php?option=session&user=" + encodeURIComponent($user) ,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The concerned Ajax part will read the database through "read.php" with the specified option, therefore only this portion will be executed :

```
else if($option=="session"){
session_start();
$user=$_GET['user'];
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user'" );
$query->execute();
$row=$query->fetch();
if($row['status']==1){$_SESSION['status']=true;}else{$_SESSION['status']=false;}
$_SESSION['user']=$row['user'];
unset($conn);unset($query);
}
```

So the problem is located within the js handler of the log in form. 
I've been adding some => to highlight the lines that creates the problem. 
I figured that without an alert after the ajax call, the code would directly return true, without worrying about the completion of the ajax execution which is supposed to go through the read.php so that it can actually update the Session informations which are used to display the page in the loader.php

I've been trying to setTimeOut the return, and that gave me the "wrong logs" message, so that meant that even if it doesn't execute the return true statement it would just continue in the execution of the same page script without worriying about the ajax() completion which is necessary.

I've also tried to set a callback function in which i would put the return so that it would execute after the ajax call, but it showed me an undefined return type. I made it like this i think :

```
function sessionStart(callback){
   AJAX("startSession");
   return callback();
}
function callback(){
   return true;
 }
```

and then i would replace the 3 problematic lines with something like that

```
sessionStart(callback);
```

I'm wondering if my guesses about the problem are true, and if so what's the proper way to solve this issue ?

Comment: `if($users[i]['user'].trim() == $user.trim() && $users[i]['password'] == $pass.trim()){` Are you really sending back a list of all the users and their passwords?

Comment: judging by your code, anyone could view/debug the source code of the page in their browser tools and steal all the usernames and passwords of all your users. You should be verifying the login details on the _server-side_ and **never** exposing passwords or other security details to the browser. I've seen some insecure stuff on the site in the past but I think this might be the best one yet.

Comment: you can use ajax to check the security if you want to avoid the page reloading. What you're doing now is just giving away all your users' login details to anyone who decides to look.

Comment: Oh yes now that i think of it i can fix it pretty quickly and still have it run with ajax but my problem still remains. I was about to review my security settings at some points anyway, i'm just new to ajax using, so i wanted to make sure i was able to extract data without really worrying about the sec. I would do that later on that's for certain

Comment: added to that, your SQL code is vulnerable to injection attacks. A malicious input value could be used to steal, corrupt or destroy the data, or even (if you haven't set your DB user's permissions correctly) alter or destroy the database itself. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for simple (and humorous) explanation of the risk, and also some examples of how to do it properly in PHP using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I know how to prevent against that it's not the current side i'm working on right now, it will come pretty soon, but before that i wanna make sure the basic features works ok. Security wil come right after that

Comment: security should be the first thing, IMHO, but there you go. Personally I don't see the point of writing it "casually", and then re-writing it "securely" afterwards, you just end up writing (and, more onerously) testing your application twice. Especially with the sql query, it's one extra line of code to add the parameter, it hardly costs you much to do it properly the first time. But then when you're happy with all the functionality, you come to change those lines of code for DB access to use parameters, you have to test everything all over again in case you made a mistake in doing it.

Comment: anyway, regarding your stated problem. It's not entirely clear. Which ajax call is the problem? It sort of sounds like you're trying to continue doing something in Javascript (although exactly what you're doing, you haven't said) while the ajax call is executing, but at the same time, that process actually needs some info from the ajax call in order to complete its processing correctly? Is that correct? Your explanation is a bit jumbled if I'm honest. If you need the data from the ajax call in order to do something, you have to wait for ajax to complete and execute your process afterwards.

Comment: Ajax runs asynchronously, as I think you've grasped, so JavaScript that relies on completion of the ajax must be executed within (or within a function that is called from) the onreadystatechange callback. There's no other way than that to guarantee it will be executed in the correct sequence. In your case you could make your AJAX function accept another parameter "callback" which could be anonymous function which should be executed when the ajax completes, and expects the response from ajax given to it as a parameter. Then in onreadystatechange you simply write `callback(this.responseText);`

Comment: and you've then got a re-usable AJAX wrapper which can execute any code you decide to give it when ajax completes. You could also extend it by doing the same with any code which you want to execute when an ajax error occurs. You're already using jQuery, so I'll mention that jQuery's `$.ajax()` function already does all of that, and more. You could save yourself a lot of trouble by using that, plus the syntax is a bit more user-friendly IMO. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . There are also various shortcut methods for simple standard get/post requests.